# Finding multiple repetitions of smaller lists in a large cumulative list

Tags: python, list

I have a large list of strings, for eg:

```
full_log = ['AB21','BG54','HG89','NS72','Error','CF54','SD62','KK02','FE34']
```

and multiple small list of strings, for eg:

```
tc1 = ['HG89','NS72']
tc2 = ['AB21','BG54']
tc3 = ['KK02','FE34']
tc4 = ['CF54','SD62']
```

I want to find each of this smaller lists in the larger list maintaining the sequence, so that the output would be something like:

```
tc2-tc1-Er-tc4-tc3
```

I want to know if there is any straight forward, pythonic way of dealing with this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a map (dictionary) of the elements of your small list:

```
m = {k: v for k, v in zip(map(tuple, [tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4])), ["tc1", "tc2", "tc3", "tc4"])}
>>> {('KK02', 'FE34'): 'tc3', ('AB21', 'BG54'): 'tc2', ('CF54', 'SD62'): 'tc4', ('HG89', 'NS72'): 'tc1'}
```

You could then use an iterator to loop over the list:

```python
itr = iter(full_log)

for i in itr:
    if i != "Error":
        n = next(itr)
        if n != "Error":
            if (i, n) in m:
                print m[(i, n)]
        else:
            print "Er"
    else:
        print "Er"



>>> tc2
    tc1
    Er
    tc4
    tc3
```

If you dont mind expanding your "Error" entries in the first list:

```
full_log2 = [item for sublist in [[i] if i != "Error" else ["Error", "Error"] for i in full_log] for item in sublist]
>>> ['AB21', 'BG54', 'HG89', 'NS72', 'Error', 'Error', 'CF54', 'SD62', 'KK02', 'FE34']
```

Then you could use a list comprehension:

```
print [m[(full_log2[i], full_log2[i+1])] if (full_log2[i], full_log2[i+1]) in m else "Er" for i in range(0, len(full_log2)-1, 2)]
>>> ['tc2', 'tc1', 'Er', 'tc4', 'tc3']
```

Comment: This is cool :) ... Thanks a lot...I like the simplicity...hope this works.

Comment: Works great if the number of elements in the smaller list is less. In my case the smaller lists have close to 200 elements and the large list has close to 5000 elements. Do you have any suggestions for this situation? I liked @niemmi 's approach, but was expecting something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

In case all your short lists are equal length you could just create a `dict` where key is `tuple` of strings and value is one of the labels. The you could go through `full_log`, take a block with suitable length and see if that can be found from `dict`.

In case the short lists are different lengths the above approach won't work since the block length to take from `full_log` is not constant. In that case one possible solution is to add items from short lists to a tree structure where the leaf node is a label. Then for every index in `full_log` see if you can find a path from tree. If path is found jump it's length forward, otherwise try from next index:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice

full_log = ['AB21','BG54','HG89','NS72','Error','CF54','SD62','KK02','FE34']

# Construct a tree
dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)
labels = defaultdict(dd)
labels['HG89']['NS72'] = 'tc1'
labels['AB21']['BG54'] = 'tc2'
labels['KK02']['FE34'] = 'tc3'
labels['CF54']['SD62'] = 'tc4'

# Find label, return tuple (label, length) or (None, 1)
def find_label(it):
    length = 0
    node = labels
    while node and isinstance(node, dict):
        node = node.get(next(it, None))
        length += 1

    return node, (length if node else 1)

i = 0
result = []
while i < len(full_log):
    label, length = find_label(islice(full_log, i, None))
    result.append(label if label else full_log[i])
    i += length

print result # ['tc2', 'tc1', 'Error', 'tc4', 'tc3']
```

The tree used above is kind of [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with an exception that nodes can either contain children or a value (label).

Comment: Thanks a lot :), the second solution suits my purpose. I liked the approach. Using graphs never occurred to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for pattern matching:

```
from sets import Set
full_log = ['AB21','BG54','HG89','NS72','Error','CF54','SD62','KK02','FE34']

tc1 = ['HG89','NS72']
tc2 = ['AB21','BG54']
tc3 = ['KK02','FE34']
tc4 = ['CF54','SD62']

set(full_log) & set(tc1)
```

output: `{'HG89', 'NS72'}`

```
#Finding index of set elements:

result=set(full_log) & set(tc1)



def all_indices(value, qlist):
    indices = []
    idx = -1
    while True:
        try:
            idx = qlist.index(value, idx+1)
            indices.append(idx)
        except ValueError:
            break
    return indices


r=[]
for i in range(len(result)):
   s=all_indices(list(result)[i], full_log)
   r.append(s)

r
Output: [[2], [3]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I have considered that, but the problem with set is it doesn't preserve the order.

Comment: what if you can find index of all set elements? I have edited my answer.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, all_indices is a built in function?

Comment: I apologize, I forgotten to add function definition in answer